# Uncaught type error when loading TextGeometry font

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to use a loaded typeface.js font, as provided by Three.js examples, yet I keep on getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.addShapeList is not a function
```

I've checked Three.js file, I'm using the build version from the three.js master branch, for the reasoning for the error and it seems that `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry` scoped `this` is missing all the prototype methods declared previously.

Altering the code to use `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.addShapeList` instead of `this.addShapeList` failed later on when reaching method `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry.prototype.addShape` by failing to recognize the vertices array of the scope.

I'm of course doing something wrong in creating the TextGeometry yet I'm unable to figure what.

This is the code I use to load the font, creating the TextGeometry object and adding it to the scene.

```
loader.load('./fonts/gentilis_bold.typeface.js', function(response){
        font = response;
        var text = THREE.TextGeometry('Some Text', {
            font: font,
            size: 70
        });

        scene.add(text);
    });
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6kv6uzhb/) to showcase my issue.

Comment: why would you not just use `THREE.TextGeometry('Some Text', { font: response, ... } );`? post a jsfiddle if you can

Comment: font exists and is of type THREE.font, the problem is when using TextGeometry there are issues popping, as mentioned in the original question.
I'll set a fiddle soon and will share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot about the `new` operator:

`var text = new THREE.TextGeometry('Some Text', {`

[ https://jsfiddle.net/kmny9gbc/ ]